# Rails - List of Files inside a folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-directory

I have a module and which have some files under the module

```
module Man
```

which has some five files called

```
module man
   module head
      def a
      end
   end
end

module man
   module hand
      def a
      end
   end
end
```

I need to access list of sub-modules that are under the module 'man' and also I need to access the list of methods in each sub-modules.

I tried doing this

```
      array_notification_classes = Dir.entries("app/models/notifications").select {|f| !File.directory? f}
```

But it returned a list of submodules which is a string.

```
 array_notification_classes  = ["head.rb", "hand.rb"]
```

From now how should I get the list of method names from each sub-module?

Comment: For ur reference `module Mod
  include Math
  CONST = 1
  def meth
    #  ...
  end
end
Mod.class              #=> Module
Mod.constants          #=> [:CONST, :PI, :E]
Mod.instance_methods   #=> [:meth]`

Comment: Use `.constantize` to change the string into Module and call `instance_methods` and it returns method names

Comment: @nishanthan, if these module are loaded (referenced), it's fine. However, until they're not referenced, they won't be visible in a such approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
My array_notification_classes = ["head.rb", "hand.rb"]        

 array_notification_classes.each do |notification_class|
    notification_class = "Notifications::#{notification_class[0..-4].classify}".constantize
    notification_class_methods = notification_class.instance_methods
 end
```

This returned all the instance methods in Notifications::Head, notifications::Hand

Answer (score 1):

Having an array of file names, e.g. array_notification_classes  = ["head.rb", "hand.rb"]

```
array_notification_classes.each do |file_name|
  require file_name
  include file_name.split(".").first.classify.constantize
end
```

or into a class:

```
class Notification
end

array_notification_classes.each do |file_name|
  require file_name
  Notification.class_eval do
    include file_name.split(".").first.classify.constantize
  end
end
```

Comment: I got this error whan i tried your code in console.LoadError:  cannot load such file -- hand.rb
from /home/ameex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rb/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'